# How do I install new Java Development Kit (JDK) on MAC OSX Mavericks?

Tags: java, maven

How do I install new Java Development Kit (JDK) on MAC OSX Mavericks? 
I tried to follow the apache instructions, but failed miserably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is installing Maven on a 64-bit Mac running Mac OSX 'Mavericks'. I was trying to follow this, which failed because the location of the java_home has changed on Mavericks:

http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

I found this website, which recommends you Install homebrew and follow the instructions on this page: http://techspunky.blogspot.in/2013/10/how-to-install-maven-on-mac-osx-109.html

once complete, don't panic when $ maven -version doesn't work, instead use $mvn --version as maven.apache.org/download.cgi recommended.

It worked, but then I noticed the Java SDK Maven was using was Java version: 1.6.0_65, which is not the latest SDK I installed on the system.

Once I set the JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`

It was using the correct SDK: 
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.1.1/libexec
Java version: 1.7.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.9", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

Success!
but wait...
next time I opened the terminal it went back to java version 1.6. WTH!

its some sort of supposed bug from what I read use:
echo JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7` | sudo tee -a /etc/mavenrc

and now:

Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.1.1/libexec
Java version: 1.7.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.9", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

Closed terminal re-opened and success!